# This domain has no IPv6 DNS server, this may prevent some IPv6-only users from reaching it

Tags: networking, ipv6, node.js, apple

Apple rejected app update, because it doesn't work with ipv6 connection.
App connects to server over websocket (socket.io, NodeJS, Express). App uses subdomain address to connect to server.

I've set up a Google Load Balancer with two "frontends". One is regular ipv4, another one is ipv6.

I can reach server using load balancer's ipv4 address directly, so i assume this means i've done it correctly.

Load balancer's external reserved ipv6 address looks like that:

`[9999:9999:0:9999::]:80`

I've added "AAAA" DNS record to subdomain. After accepting this address, DNS editor shows it like that:

`9999:9999:0000:9999:0000:0000:0000:0000`

Services like this one: http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php
Are showing these results: http://prntscr.com/i8fk9j

As you can see on the screenshot, among other messages it says this:

> This domain has no IPv6 DNS server, this may prevent some IPv6-only users from reaching it.

I've created hotspot as described [here by apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) (Test for IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatibility Regularly) and connected iphone to this hotspot.
App can't connect to server.
I've also tried to reach healthcheck in Safari address while on the same phone with the same connection. It returns correct response "true", but this has nothing to do with websocket - it's simple REST listener.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Obfuscating the IP information makes it difficult to provide you useful troubleshooting information. Providing the DNS RRs would also help.

Comment: This issue has to do with your iOS application code, not the DNS setup of your domain. While this is something that should be fixed eventually by your DNS provider, it is not the cause of your Apple app store rejection. You need to be fixing the bugs in your code.

Comment: You are asking about three separate issues and you haven't provided sufficient information about any of them to get much of an answer. If you edit your question to cover just one of the three issues and provide sufficient detail your question may be reopened. For the DNS issue I find the error message quite clear. If you want more detail you should mention the domain name. As for the load balancer setup I don't see anything in your question indicating a problem exists. The problem with your app is probably off-topic here, and you haven't given us enough information to help you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The message seems not to be about your AAAA records, but about the address of the DNS server for your domain. Even when your domain has AAAA records, IPv6 only users cannot reach it if they cannot reach the DNS server for your domain.